# How to download image with ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working on Php and Ajax,I want to show "preview" on click which is working in index.php And want to download image after click on "Download"
button with ajax(download.php),But right now download button not working
Here is my code in index.php(showing review successfully)

```
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
       Lorem Ipsum dummy text ...
    </div>
    
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () 
    {
        var type="download";
            $.ajax({
             url:'download.php',
             type:"post",
             data:{type:type},
             processData:false,
             contentType:false,
             cache:false,
             async:false,
             success: function(data)
                {
                        alert(data);
                 },
             });
        return false;
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    }
    );

});
</script>
```

And here is my download.php,I tried with "trigger" function but not working,Where i am wrong ?

```
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 5000px;
        Lorem Ipsum dummy text...
    </div>
    
      <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>

<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
$("#btn-Preview-Image").trigger("click");
setTimeout(function() {
     $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").trigger("click");
}, 5000);
});

var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You say `download` but do you mean `upload` instead? The ajax callback simply alerts a message and is sending data to the server.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius: no i just want to download not upload

Comment: From the server to the browser yes? You would not use AJAX for that purpose